# Why is $E(\Omega) $ a Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E(\Omega)=\{u \in L^2(\Omega):\operatorname{div} u \in L^2(\Omega) \}$.
Let $[\cdot, \cdot]$ be a scalar product on $E(\Omega) $ such that $[u,v]=\langle u,v\rangle_{L^2} + \int_{\Omega}\operatorname{div} u \cdot \operatorname{div} v$.

Why is $E(\Omega)$ a Hilbert space with this scalar product?

Comment: What do you mean by $\operatorname{div} u$? Is $u$ vector-valued?

Comment: @JackyChong Yes!

Comment: If $u$ is vector-valued then $\operatorname{div} u$ is a scalar. So what do you mean when you say $u \in L^2(\Omega)$ and $\operatorname{div} u \in L^2(\Omega)$?